# how do i create a declining array of np.zeros from a starting length in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to create this with numpy without using a python [] array:

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0])
 array([0])]
```

currently i'm using this but is there a pure numpy way to do this?

```
import numpy as np

# Lengths for each array
lengths = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# Create a NumPy universal function (ufunc) to produce arrays of zeros with specified lengths
zeros_array = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.zeros(x, dtype=int), 1, 1)

# Use the ufunc to create the list of NumPy arrays
arrays_list = list(zeros_array(lengths))

print(arrays_list)
```

Comment: To avoid a Python list, you can write `arrays_list = np.array(zeros_array(lengths))`

Comment: `[np.zeros(i) for i in lengths]` is the best way to make such a list of arrays.  You are welcome to test that against your `list(...frompyfunc...)` version.  In general if you want a list of something, use a list comprehension, and don't try to fool yourself into thinking there's some 'magical' pure-numpy way of making a list.  There isn't.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a loop as i'm trying to create a jit, then a cuda.jit implementation of this but it that is the best way i will figure it out :-)

Comment: @hpaulj definitely faster what you mentioned: Time taken with NumPy ufunc approach: 0.36165 seconds
Time taken with list comprehension approach: 0.05944 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `lengths` list, you can do with `range(7,0,-1)`

```
np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.zeros(x, dtype=int), 1, 1)(range(7,0,-1))
```

Or as suggested by @hpaulj

```
[np.zeros(i) for i in range(7,0,-1)]
```

Comment: the zeros function was the fastest with a timeit() and i'm working on getting it to work with numba as the function itsself was much faster. i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite what you want - numpy doesn't support [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) - but numpy does have masked arrays which this makes use of;

```
>>> np.ma.array(np.zeros((7,7)),mask=np.tril(np.ones((7,7))).T-np.eye(7))

masked_array(
  data=[[0.0, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, --, --, --, --, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, --, --, --, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, --, --, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, --, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, --],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
  mask=[[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```